# VBA - Do..While Loop inside For Loop

Tags: excel, vba, loops, nested-loops

I'm learning VBA and I tried nesting a do-while-loop inside a for-loop, but the outer for-loop doesn't seem to have an effect (whole Sub only runs once), although its runs without errors. Could someone please assist me? :)

My code:

```
Sub DoWhileDemo()
    Dim Cnt As Integer
    Cells(1, 1).Activate 'just meant as an in-case

    For Cnt = 1 To 100 Step 1
        Do While ActiveCell.Value <> Empty
            ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Value * 2
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        Loop
    Next Cnt
End Sub
```

Comment: youre going to be more descriptive about the problem, please tell us more about what you would expect to happen and what actually happens and then we can help you

Comment: Have you put a break point and check `ActiveCell` is not empty? And should it be `ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate`? If not, it just keep checking and working on `A1`

Comment: @CodeWarrior I would expect the For loop to have an effect (ie, run the do..while loop 100 times instead of just 1 as I mentioned) and what is actually happening is that the do..while loop is only run once, as mentioned. If you look at the code (and run it), its like the For loop wasn't there.

Comment: @Prisoner no no, its going over all my cells that aren't empty. I would have noticed :p The Do..while loop is working fine, but I would like it to be run 100 times. So that if I start with A1 value of 55, I should be getting a bigger number than 110 after running the sub

Comment: After the first iteration where you set a value in the `ActiveCell` (which is not a recommended way to do this), you set the cell in the next row. If that cell is empty, it will never trigger your `Do While` loop and hence nothing will ever get done. Move your `ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select` outside your `Do While` loop. That might help

Comment: @Zac nop, the do..while loop is fine (got it from VBA for Dummies, I just added a For loop and a A1 cell-activation). I just needed to put Cells(1,1).Activate as first line in my FOR loop and it be working! :)

Comment: @ianquiksilver then what is the point of your `FOR` loop if you are always going to select the same cell throughout each iteration?

Comment: On a side node, you don't need to put `Step 1` in the `For` loop, since it is the default step size.

Answer (score 2):

When `cnt=1` the do while loop ends when `ActiveCell` is empty. At this moment the `ActiveCell` is empty, so for `cnt=2` to `100`, the do while loop is never executed.

move the `cells(1,1).activate` after the `for` instruction

Comment: To elaborate. If you want to perform the stepwise multiplication (i.e. run the `do while` loop mulitple times), you need to go back to the first cell, in the begining of each iteration of the `for` loop.

Comment: @Noceo yes, you are correct :) I figured it out right before your comment but still thanks for the input :)

Answer (score 1):

Nop, i just needed to put Cells(1,1).Activate as first line in the For loop to make sure it kept being brought back to "start" so that the while loop could then run through, I fixed the code. Issue is resolved :)

```
Sub DoWhileDemo()
    Dim Cnt As Integer
    For Cnt = 1 To 100 Step 1
        Cells(1, 1).Activate
        Do While ActiveCell.Value <> Empty
            ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Value * 2
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        Loop
    Next Cnt
End Sub
```

Comment: a little confuse ... what the code `ActiveCell.Offset` do?  And you can _mark as answer_ later, seems 1 or 2 days.